# How to move inside subplot Draggable within main subplot Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

after a lot of search and getting help from [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) as well as from stackoverflow i got a something but still solution is not proper way.

Here is my code:

i am using `RectangleSelector` to move and stretch the the inset axes of main axes of matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as widgets

def onselect(eclick, erelease):
    if eclick.ydata<erelease.ydata:
        erelease.ydata,eclick.ydata=eclick.ydata,erelease.ydata
    if eclick.xdata<erelease.xdata:
        erelease.xdata,eclick.xdata=eclick.xdata,erelease.xdata
    axes2.set_ylim(eclick.ydata,erelease.ydata)
    axes2.set_xlim(eclick.xdata,erelease.xdata)
    axes2.set_position([eclick.xdata,eclick.ydata,erelease.xdata,erelease.ydata])
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig = plt.figure()
axes1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
axes2 = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3])

axes2.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=None)

rp = dict(facecolor='white',edgecolor = 'black', alpha=0.5, fill=True)

rs=widgets.RectangleSelector(axes1, onselect, drawtype='box',interactive=True,
                             spancoords='pixels',rectprops = rp )

plt.show()
```

here it `RectangleSelector` suppose to be with `axes2` and it should draggable and stretchable along with it. When i am moving `RectangleSelector` separately in `axes1` and at time the when i am releasing `RectangleSelector` at that time `axes2` also changing it's position and size also changing.what i suppose to do now.please help me out on this.thanks in advance.