# Matplotlib make image Stretchable by mouse event

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib

How Can i make this image stretchable using mouse event in matplotlib. please help.

Here the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as image
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

fig = plt.figure()

X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Y = [1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 8, 6]

mainaxes = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8]) # main axes

img = image.imread('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png')
z = 0.3 + 0.3
imagebox = OffsetImage(img, zoom=z)
imgbox = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (0.3,0.5), frameon=True)
mainaxes.add_artist(imgbox)

imgbox.draggable()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Similar question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189919/how-to-move-inside-subplot-draggable-within-main-subplot-matplotlib) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226851/matplotlib-axessubplots-draggable-subplot?noredirect=1&lq=1). The fact that they don't have any answer yet, might point to the question being too broad and no attempt being shown towards a solution. The solution is also complex enough such that people will not simply write it down for you. Better divide the problem into small pieces. Are you able to register mouse move events?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes,i am able to register mouse move events in a different way.at first i have tried `draggable()` but it didn't work on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189919/how-to-move-inside-subplot-draggable-within-main-subplot-matplotlib) after that i found different program on draggable where it drag a scatter point. i just modified that program and try to make draggable inaxes of Matplotlib but still it's not working giving error.

Comment: It will often be much more purposeful to show the attempt and the error and ask about the actual problem you encounter than asking for a general solution.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i have posted the problem below answer along with ouput.

Comment: So you found a solution? That's nice.

Comment: found a solution but i getting error so as usually it haven't solve yet. i have posted the solution what i have got as well as what problem it arise when i have some change.